# Canjs vs. Knockout?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, mvvm, knockout.js, javascript-framework

I'm to start some projects with [Knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/), however, recently I found [Canjs](http://canjs.us/).

- What are Cons and Pros of canjs vs knockoutjs?
- Which one is more suitable for different type-size web apps (small apps / large scale projects/ enterprise apps )?

As I study a bit, I found canjs more productive, light wight and functional, but I don't have any experience over it yet.

Also, may I ask folks to add [Canjs](http://canjs.us/) tag to *Stackoverflow* please?

Comment: CanJS actually uses a decent pattern and isn't an ugly hack on top of HTML. CanJS does suffer from bloat. Consider using [stapes](http://hay.github.com/stapes/) isntead of canjs

Comment: Does **Stapes.js** support observable, bindings, MVVM or MVC patterns?

Comment: No, according to its' [Philosophy](http://hay.github.com/stapes/#m-phil) "No. Stapes doesn't have any pre-defined Models, Views or Controllers. It also doesn't have Collections, Routers, or stuff you might find in other libraries (remember, it's tiny :)."

Comment: @Raynos: Why you think "CanJS does suffer from bloat"? it's only 8.5 kb.

Comment: Because You don't need a Model or a View or a Controller, you just need EventEmitters and Observables

Comment: @RezaOwliaei: Stapes does support observables, with a powerful yet simple event system, because it's the basis for many patterns. You also have data methods. In short: you can create any pattern you want because they all share those basics. You just need to implement it yourself :)

Comment: @Raynos Canjs is quite modular, if one don't need model, view one may just not use it (not include in the build).

Comment: @WHITECOLOR that's not how you do modular code. Modular code is opt-in not opt-out

Comment: @Raynos that doesn't make much sense. If you can opt-out of every feature, then you can opt-in on each feature.  You can just use CanJS's observe layer.  However, can.Control is extremely useful for binding / memory safety.

Comment: @Raynos If CanJS is bloated, then Stapes is anemic.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest taking a look through all the different options at:

TodoMVC
http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/

Looking through the source code of the options there will give you a good feel of how the different frameworks compare.

My personal feeling is there are basically two approaches between all of them:

1. Using jquery selectors with 1 way bindings and verbose templating engines(most frameworks)
2. Naming convention approach with 2 way binding in MVVM pattern (knockoutjs)

Personally I find option 2 results in writing less code, which is something I strive for.

Answer (score 0):

there are loads of JavaScript frameworks, besides the 2 you mention. It is hard to compare them, as they have other intentions/purposes. I don't know about CanJS but I am sure the goal of them is different than KnockOut. Choosing which framework to use really depends on what website you use, and what its functionality is, rather than the functionality of the FrameWork.

So choose what suits your project best, in any case, every choice. Not just a JavaScript framework.

Specific questions can be asked and compared (not sure if SO is suited for it). Example is comparing templating of different frameworks, or data-binding. But comparing 2 frameworks is not recommended without knowing the website (or the to be website)

Comment: I'm trying to know when should I use each of them. You are right, there are some common features between different js frameworks. I don't know when I should choose which? What are the goals of each framework?

Comment: What does your application need to do? See if you can find a framework which does that. Do they do that both, than take the easiest to use (in your opinion, not mine) and/or the lightest/fastest.